# broadcast client disconnect to a particular room

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am following this excellent [Tutorial](http://modernweb.com/2013/09/30/building-multiplayer-games-with-node-js-and-socket-io/) to make my first test game in node.js

Everything is working perfectly. Even when I changed it from two player to three player, still worked fine. But unfortunately the tutorial did not cover the `disconnect event`. Every event on server is happening against some client action. e.g join game, answer click etc.

But i am stuck at broadcasting to all clients in a room when one of the user looses his internet connection because he performs no action to do that. By some search i found something like following

```
// Listen for Socket.IO Connections. Once connected, start the game logic.
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket)
{
    //console.log('client connected');
    initGame(io, socket);
    io.sockets.on('disconnect', function ()
    {
        socket.broadcast.emit('playerDisconnected', 'x has disconnected');
    });
});
```

This is not working. And I cant understand how to know and how to tell users in a room that who has disccented. Please guide me what i can do more to make question clear.

**Edit**

With the help of given answer I am able to broadcast a disconnect event to all clients connected to the server. But what can i do to emit only to the particular game clients mean **from where i could get gameid/roomid in this event**. I see something like game socket in my working code/ (following is it). but I tried simple `socket.emit('playerDisconnected', 'x has disconnected');` it does not work and `emit.broadcast` works but not as i need

```
function initGame(sio, socket)
{
    io = sio;
    gameSocket = socket;
    gameSocket.emit('app_ev_connected', { message: "You are connected!" });

    gameSocket.on('serv_ev_playerJoinGame', playerJoinGame);
    gameSocket.on('serv_ev_getRooms',getRooms);    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you need to add the disconnect event on the socket itself?

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

   initGame(io, socket);
   socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      //socket.broadcast.emit('playerDisconnected', 'x has disconnected');
      socket.broadcast.emit('playerDisconnected', this.id + ' has disconnected');
      //if you want to emit in particular room
      io.sockets.in('roomName').emit('playerDisconnected', this.id +' has disconnected');
   });
});
```

Comment: Could i know What is x? I have written because I dont know who is disconnected. But is there a way how to know and tell who is disconnected.. mean who is x?

Comment: You need to store some kind of data that identifies the user. For example when they connect if they are authenticated you can store a userid in the socket object. Then you can tell others which user disconnected using that userid.

Comment: Yes. thanks but it is broadcasting to all clients. I need only to particular room/game players. See my edit plz

Comment: If you want to emit to a particular room use `io.sockets.in('roomName').emit('playerDisconnected', 'x has disconnected');`

Comment: How could i know the room name.. in this event.. that is the problem.. U see the code, I even dont know where from the socket is received to this function. As it is not triggered from client side code.. So how to figure out roomname here

Comment: Again you need to store extra data, ie a list of rooms the user has  has joined then you iterate through those and emit the disconnected event to each one.

Answer (score 2):

I had a suggestion which makes more sense in a comment but since I don't have enough reps I couldn't add it.

So I use the userData from my JWT authentication middleware where I put the room number and regenerate the token where I push the room details too!

More on [SocketIO Middleware](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace-use-fn)
More on [JWT Auth](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/06/nodejs-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api)